# is it possible to add a toolTip to a SmartGWT listGrid cell on hover?

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

is it possible to add a toolTip to a SmartGWT listGrid cell on hover ? 
and how if possible? 
i cant fined any method that adds a toolTip directly to the cell on hover ,
 can any one help me please ?

Comment: Check this [sample in SmartGWT showcase](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#grid_interaction_value_hover). Click on the "View Source" button in that (above Overview) to check the source code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ListGridField governmentField = new ListGridField("government", "Government", 120);
    governmentField.setShowHover(true);
    governmentField.setHoverCustomizer(new HoverCustomizer() {
        public String hoverHTML(Object value, ListGridRecord record, int rowNum, int colNum) {
            CountryRecord countryRecord = (CountryRecord) record;
            int governmentDesc = countryRecord.getGovernmentDesc();
            String[] governmentDescription = new String[]{
              "<b>Communism</b> - a system of government in which the state plans and controls the economy and a single - often authoritarian - party holds power; state controls are imposed with the elimination of private ownership of property or capital while claiming to make progress toward a higher social order in which all goods are equally shared by the people (i.e., a classless society).",
              "<b>Constitutional monarchy</b> - a system of government in which a monarch is guided by a constitution whereby his/her rights, duties, and responsibilities are spelled out in written law or by custom.",
              "<b>Federal republic</b> - a state in which the powers of the central government are restricted and in which the component parts (states, colonies, or provinces) retain a degree of self-government; ultimate sovereign power rests with the voters who chose their governmental representatives.",
              "<b>Federal (Federative)</b> - a form of government in which sovereign power is formally divided - usually by means of a constitution - between a central authority and a number of constituent regions (states, colonies, or provinces) so that each region retains some management of its internal affairs; differs from a confederacy in that the central government exerts influence directly upon both individuals as well as upon the regional units.",
              "<b>Parliamentary monarchy</b> - a state headed by a monarch who is not actively involved in policy formation or implementation (i.e., the exercise of sovereign powers by a monarch in a ceremonial capacity); true governmental leadership is carried out by a cabinet and its head - a prime minister, premier, or chancellor - who are drawn from a legislature (parliament).",
              "<b>Republic</b> - a representative democracy in which the people's elected deputies (representatives), not the people themselves, vote on legislation."
      };
            return governmentDescription[governmentDesc];
        }
    });
```

from: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/GWT/TablecellhovertooltipSmartGWT.htm